# ModuleNotFoundError while importing Airflow DAG

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am currently working with a local installation of Airflow on Ubuntu, and this works perfectly for simple DAGs.

I now have a DAG that has dependencies on other modules, and I am stuck with a ModuleNotFound error that stops me from importing the DAG.

The *my_dag.py* file has a line that tries to import from the *module1.py* python file. I'm attempting to do this with:

```
from my_project.common_modules.module1 import *
```

I then get a Broken DAG import error that says **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'.**

My folder structure is:

```
dags
| .airflowignore 
| my_project
              | __init__.py
              | common_modules
              |              |  __init__.py
              |              | module1.py
              | my_dag.py
```

I have been following the guide here - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/modules_management.html.

I have checked that my PYTHONPATH and airflow.cfg file correctly reflects the ~/airflow/dags folder. The content of my .airflowignore file is simply my_project/common_modules/.* (I have tried with and without an airflowignore file). I have also tried placing the common module in various locations, including the plugins folder, with the same issue in every combination.

I would welcome assistance.

Comment: I'm not really experienced in airflow yet, but just for interest: Using `from common_modules.module1 import *` also fails?

Comment: yup, still fails unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the "my_project" folder to sys.path before the import line

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("my_project full path")
from my_project.common_modules.module1 import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your module to `plugins`.  A structure like:

```
dags
| .airflowignore 
| my_project
              | my_dag.py
plugins
| my_project
              | __init__.py
              | common_modules
              |              |  __init__.py
              |              | module1.py
```

And then the import should still work as:

```
from my_project.common_modules.module1 import *
```

This method works for me and it is how we structure imports in our Airflow environment.

See this resource: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.2/plugins.html

Comment: This was one of the alternatives I had tried with no success..the problem for me was that the location was not on the sys.path, adding it solved it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
from my_project.common_modules.module1 import *
```

Your original way of importing the module has no problem as long as airflow could identify where you put your `/dags`.

You mentioned that

```
... airflow.cfg file correctly reflects the ~/airflow/dags folder
```

I think you mean you defined `dags_folder = ~/airflow/dags`

If that is the case, please check if your project directory is `~/airflow`, instead of something like `~/my_project/airflow`. Otherwise, you would need to change the config in `airflow.cfg`

Comment: yes, I meant the dags_folder was set to airflow dags. It turned out to be a problem with my sys.path, but thank you for your answer!